# Java Jackson object mapper fails on correct variable name

Tags: java, json, jackson, dto, objectmapper

Note: I know the variables are not properly named. I am cleaning up old code from another dev who had these listed as member variables. They will be named properly and yes I know I will need the annotations for that, but what I am looking for here is an explanation as to why the variable is EmployeeId, it's looking for EmployeeID, but finding a non-existing variable mEmployeeId. BTW, this happens on the server, not just in the IDE.

For some unkown reason - after modifying variable names, saving, restarting, invalidating cache, everything - jackson is failing to map to the propper variable name. I am using intelliJ with Java for this.

Error:

```
Exception in badge service getting by badgeId: Unrecognized field 
"EmployeeId" (class com.companyName.attendance.entity.DTOs.badgeservice.BadgeDTO), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: "mBadgeId", "mEmployeeId", "mLanId", "mFirstName", "mEmail", "mLastName"]) 
at [Source: (String)"{"backoff":null,"error_id":null,"error_message":null,"error_name":null,"has_more":false,"items":[{"EmployeeId":"888888","LanId":"NTest","FirstName":"Name","MiddleName":null,"LastName":"Test","Email":null,"Location":null,"Title":null,"Phone":null,"DepartmentId":null,"DepartmentName":null,"DepartmentNumber":null,"Groups":null,"Found":false,"BadgeId":"222222","JobTitle":null,"Picture":null,"OrgUrl":null,"Manager":null,"Coworkers":null,"DirectReports":null}],"page":null,"page_size":null,"quo"[truncated 61 chars]; line: 1, column: 113] (through reference chain: com.companyName.attendance.entity.DTOs.badgeservice.BadgeServiceResponseDTO["items"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.companyName.attendance.entity.DTOs.badgeservice.BadgeDTO["EmployeeId"])
```

As you see, it's not finding EmployeeId in the DTO and says the expected feild is mEmployeeID. However, here is my DTO variable declarations:

```
public class BadgeDTO {
//TODO: Convert member variables to proper practice names
String BadgeId;
String EmployeeId;
String FirstName;
String LanId;
String LastName;
String Email;

public BadgeDTO(String BadgeId, String EmployeeId, String FirstName, 
String LanId, String LastName, String Email) {
    super();
    this.BadgeId = BadgeId;
    this.EmployeeId = EmployeeId;
    this.FirstName = FirstName;
    this.LanId = LanId;
    this.LastName = LastName;
    this.Email = Email;
}
public BadgeDTO() {
    super();
}
public String getmBadgeId() {
    return BadgeId;
}
public void setmBadgeId(String BadgeId) {
    this.BadgeId = BadgeId;
}
public String getmEmployeeId() {
    return EmployeeId;
}
public void setmEmployeeId(String EmployeeId) {
    this.EmployeeId = EmployeeId;
}
public String getmFirstname() {
    return FirstName;
}
public void setmFirstName(String FirstName) {
    this.FirstName = FirstName;
}
public String getmLanId() {
    return LanId;
}
public void setmLanId(String LanId) {
    this.LanId = LanId;
}
public String getmLastName() {
    return LastName;
}
public void setmLastName(String LastName) {
    this.LastName = LastName;
}
public String getmEmail() {
    return Email;
}
public void setmEmail(String Email) {
    this.Email = Email;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "BadgeDTO [BadgeId=" + BadgeId + ", EmployeeId=" + EmployeeId + 
", Firstname=" + FirstName
            + ", LanId=" + LanId + ", LastName=" + LastName + ", Email=" + 
Email + "]";
}
}
```

Now the crazy thing is, that doing the following works:

```
@JsonProperty("BadgeId")
String BadgeId;
@JsonProperty("EmployeeId")
String EmployeeId;
@JsonProperty("FirstName")
String FirstName;
```

JSON:

```
{
"backoff": null,
"error_id": null,
"error_message": null,
"error_name": null,
"has_more": false,
"items": [
    {
        "EmployeeId": "888888",
        "LanId": "TName",
        "FirstName": "Test",
        "MiddleName": null,
        "LastName": "Name",
        "Email": null,
        "Location": null,
        "Title": null,
        "Phone": null,
        "DepartmentId": null,
        "DepartmentName": null,
        "DepartmentNumber": null,
        "Groups": null,
        "Found": false,
        "BadgeId": "222222",
        "JobTitle": null,
        "Picture": null,
        "OrgUrl": null,
        "Manager": null,
        "Coworkers": null,
        "DirectReports": null
    }
],
"page": null,
"page_size": null,
"quota_max": null,
"quota_remaining": null,
"total": null,
"type": null
}
```

So, I have fixed the issue using the JsonProperty annotations above, but why in the world is it still looking for mEmployeeId when it exists no where in the entirety of my code? I figured invalidate/restart would fix this, but it did not

Comment: Good practice in Java is start instance/variable name with lower case: String String BadgeId should be String badgeId;...

Comment: Yes, I understand this, however I am cleaning up some stuff from another developer and I usually start with minimal changes and improve them. These were all set as member variables for some odd reason and in the process of converting, I started getting this weird error. I then capitalized everything back to be exactly as expected and figure out what is all going on. This is less about the improper code practice and more about why in the world this thing is looking finding a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you have getters and setters defined for the fields?  If yes, include the pair for EmployeeId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is,
as it often is: Pay Attention To The Code You Write.

The getters and setters expose the fields as m* (where * is the actual field name).

Look at this:

```
getmEmployeeId(
   ^
   |
```

This is the letter 'm'.

Thus this exposes the field name as "mEmployeeId"

More details:
The value returned by the method has nothing to do with the name of the value that is exposed by the getter.
Java demands that getter names have the format "getFieldName" and 
that setter nanes have the format "setFieldName"
where "FieldName" is any value that is not the "get" or "set" portion of the method name.

This is called the "JavaBean Naming Convention" and you absolutely must both understand it and obey it if you code in Java and use any third party Java library.

Comment: Well that would explain the issue then. I didn't know that was a requirement. I had planned to change those names, but after changing a lot of other code I wanted to make sure it was all still working before going through with a longer refactor. Didn't realize the setter and getters could cause that on their own. I figured the variables were accessible by class, not exposed by class.

Answer (score 1):

To match `JSON` keys with `POJO` properties `Jackson` uses something called `PropertyNamingStrategy`. In your `JSON` we can find at least two strategies:

1. [SNAKE_CASE](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html#SNAKE_CASE) (`page_size`, `error_message`, etc)
2. [UPPER_CAMEL_CASE](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html#UPPER_CAMEL_CASE) (`EmployeeId`, `DepartmentId`, etc)

From other side `POJO` class provides third strategy:

1. "m" + [UPPER_CAMEL_CASE](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html#UPPER_CAMEL_CASE) (`mEmployeeId`, `mDepartmentId`, etc)

This is why `JSON` does not match `POJO`. To make it work you need to implement new strategy which could look like below:

```
class MNamingStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public String nameForSetterMethod(MapperConfig<?> config, AnnotatedMethod method,
        String defaultName) {
        return defaultName.substring(1); // remove first `m` letter
    }
}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
@JsonNaming(MNamingStrategy.class)
class Clazz {

    private int Id = 11;

    public int getmId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setmId(int id) {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Clazz{" +
            "Id=" + Id +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Since now, you can deserialise above `JSON` to given `POJO`.

When you have added `@JsonProperty` annotation with property names you have told `Jackson` to use custom mapping.

See also:

1. [Spring Jackson property naming strategy](https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring/spring-jackson-property-naming-strategy/)
2. [PropertyNamingStrategy](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html)
3. [More Jackson Annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-advanced-annotations)

Comment: It turns out my actual problem was that I didn't know Java exposed everything directly with the get<VARIABLE>. I figured, getX return name would expose name, not X. So after learning that my problem is solved. I'm not looking to marry all the naming strategies, those are all being refactored since I inherited this to match proper conventions. My strategy was to change variable names, test to be safe, change function names, test again. That first test failed and I didn't realize it was because of the functions.

Comment: That's good approach. Anyway, I hope, my post helped you understand this problem a little bit better. Also, take a look on Google's code style: https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html